# Taking a Conditional Mean in Stata

Tags: statistics, stata

Let's say I have a Stata dataset that has two variables: `type` and `price`.  The `type` value for each observation is a number between 1 and 10.

I want to add a third value that is the average `price` of all variables of that `type`.  So, for example, if the first observation had a `type` of 3 and a `price` of 10, then I'd like to add a third value that is the average `price` of all observations with `type`=3.

How can I do this in Stata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a few ways to do this but this is what I'd suggest.

```
gen newvar = .
forvalues i = 1/10 {

  qui sum price if type == `i', meanonly
  replace newvar = r(mean) if type == `i'
```

}

Answer (score 6):

Here's a different approach that is more simple and efficient.  If you've got a large dataset, this will be faster than the multi-step loop aTron suggested and this approach adapts to changes in the range of your "type" variable (if your dataset changes in size, you don't have to go back through your code and change the range in the `forvalues` command).

1) Create a fake dataset

```
clear
input type price
1 1000
2 3200
3 5000
4 1200
5 1000
1 4000
2 2000
3 4000
4 1200
5 2000
end
```

2) Generate the average `price` by `type`

```
bysort type: egen meanprice = mean(price)

li type price meanprice, sepby(type)
```

Comment: "gen newvar = ." is missing before the forvalues loop

Comment: Then, I don't understand why is this loop added because it simply duplicates the `meanprice` variable. Did I miss something important?

Comment: @emeryville You didn't miss anything important at all. The last section is at best redundant and at worst quite misleading. I didn't notice myself when I last touched this question, but I've edited it out now.

Comment: Would be more interesting if the last line printed out the results with only one row per type...

Answer (score 1):

You can create the means with

```
by type: egen conditional_mean = mean(price)
```

Comment: Redundant -- this is the same as Eric's answer.